# Can we make the text in the search box darker?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

The search text in the new nav bar is light gray on white. It's a little too low-contrast for my 53-year-old eyes. I checked the previous bar on other SE sites and, while the prompt text is light gray, once I start typing in the box the text I type is black or close to it. Any chance to make the search text in the new nav bar closer to black?

Comment: Would also help differentiate it from the placeholder text ("Search...")

Comment: I'm just at the point (after maintaining 20/20 past 40!) that I'm starting to need to use reading glasses occasionally, and I agree that it's a little fuzzy for me too. It's subtle, you don't always realize that you're seeing things a little differently until you realize that you're squinting a bit.

Comment: Agreed, it's disconcerting being the same color as the placeholder text.